# bag of words for classification - features vs pixels

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, pattern-recognition

I am classifying medical images using bag-of-words model.
I did the following to extract the feature vector:

1. extract features from small image patches and then apply BOW on
   those features
2. extract pixel values from small image patches then apply BOW on those pixel values

After the feature extraction I tried PCA, feature selection, changing no of clusters for KMeans etc to improve the accuracy. But in my case BOW learned on pixel values (1) outperforms (90%) than the BOW learned on features(2) (70%). My features are good and when I use those features to classify the images using some other framework I was able to get more than 95% accuracy.

My question is why BOW learned on pixels performs better than BOW learned on features?

[image]
[image]

Normal-abnormal colonoscopy image classification

```
    Figure 1: a normal colon image
    Figure 2: an image with polyp
```

Comment: Could you show some images if possible and tell what categories you are trying to identify?

Comment: It is a normal vs abnormal colonoscopy image classification.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what that would look like..

Comment: Please look at the figures that I uploaded now.

Comment: And what features are you extracting?

Comment: @ user570593 Hi, i would like to know whose work you are following a reference, I mean every field has a state of art and set of good research works or Phd thesis... can you link your reference so that we will be more clear about what you are trying???

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of your two methods for extracting features from an image patch are

Feature selection = "run PCA, k-means, or select some subset of pixels, and construct a vector of these extracted values"

Pixel Values = "create a vector from RGB values of the image"

In fact, to get good results from BOW features, people often derive individual features using relatively complicated algorithms.

In the project at http://vision.stanford.edu/projects/totalscene/index.html (paper in reference #1), the authors take BOW features from both images blocks and a segmentation. For the image blocks, they extract SIFT features, and for each segment they take shape, color, location, and texture features (see section 2.1 and follow the reference for a better description of the features they use).

In "Decomposing a Scene into Geometric and Semantically Consistent Regions." (Gould et. al.) Shape, color, edge, etc. features are derived by doing things like training boosted logistic regression classifiers, Potts models, and Gaussian Mixture models.

You probably don't need such intensive techniques to extract features that beat pixel vectors, but you should definitely browse around the literature to see what is effective.

SIFT features, color histograms, and filters to extract texture responses seem to work pretty well and also have a reasonable amount of software library support.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I tried 2: (1) extracting features (texture, color, edge, etc) (2) only color. After extracting features I tried PCA/feature selection on the extracted features/intensity values. I found on some papers saying that for intensity values having a few hundred clusters are enough but for features we should have thousands of clusters. So currently I am trying with many clusters and hope it will give me good results. I will update the results soon.